# VBA Change Cell Value On Insert

Tags: vba, excel

I apologize for the confusing title. I've run into a quirk that I don't know exactly how to describe, work around, or fix. I have an item that I pulled by value from another workbook and wish to insert it from the collection I passed back to the original function. I print it out in the debug screen and it is the correct value as follows:

```
9-06-01
```

The very next line I insert it into the appropriate cell like this:

```
Dim item As Variant

For Each item In someCollection
    Debug.Print item
    thisSht.cells(y, x).Value = item
Next item
```

When I insert it in to the cell the value becomes

```
37140
```

The value is not intended to be treated as a date and I thought it was excel trying to auto-format but that doesn't seem to be the case as once I set the correct cell formatting the issue is still there. It works for some other values such as 807-01-01. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it okay if the item is a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being treated as a date (6 Sep 2001). To work around that you can prefix it with ' or format the cell as text:

```
thisSht.cells(y, x).Value = "'" & item
```

or

```
With thisSht.cells(y, x)
.Numberformat = "@"
.Value = item
End With
```